# Caused by: com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException Error

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jsonpath, mockmvc

I am writing test case for my controller. And, I am using .andExpect method to match jsonpath expression. Below is my code:

```java
    @Test
    public void getALLEmails() throws Exception {

        Email email = new Email();
        email.setTicketID("123");

         List<Email> emails = Collections.singletonList(new Email());

        assertThat(this.emailService).isNotNull();
        given(emailService.getEmails()).willReturn(emails);

        mockMvc.perform(get("/emails"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.ticketID", is("123")));


    }
```

However, I am getting the following error;

> Error: java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$.ticketID"
>       at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.evaluateJsonPath(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:295)
>       at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.assertValue(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:72)
>       at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.JsonPathResultMatchers.lambda$value$0(JsonPathResultMatchers.java:87)
>       at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:195)
>       at com.example.rstsdemo.controller.EmailControllerTest.getALLEmails(EmailControllerTest.java:67)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
>       at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
>       at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
>   Caused by: com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: Expected to find an object with property ['ticketID'] in path $ but found 'net.minidev.json.JSONArray'. This is not a json object according to the JsonProvider: 'com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.json.JsonSmartJsonProvider'.

Please, help me find the solution to it. I believe I am using correct java expression.

I have already tried using different jsonpath expressions such as:
[0].ticketID, $.[0].ticketID and others. Thanks!

Comment: So, the problem was the Emails were saved in  

       `return "[Email: {" +
                ", ticketID='" + ticketID + '\'' + "\n" +
                ", date='" + date + '\'' + "\n" +
                ", senderName='" + senderName + '\'' + "\n" +
                ", senderAdress='" + senderAddress + '\'' + "\n" +
                ", subject='" + subject + '\'' + "\n" +
                ", recipients='" + recipients + '\'' + "\n" +
                ", body='" + body + '\'' + "\n" +
                '}]' `
So, I couldn't retrieve it by $[0].TicketID. It worked after removing "[Email:" .